# Kendo Grid Pager Shows No Items To Display

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have defined a Kendo grid as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#catalogGrid2").kendoGrid(catalogGridOptions);
});

let catalogGridOptions = {
    pageable: true,
     dataSource: {
         serverPaging: true,
         //serverGrouping: true,
         transport: {
             read: {
                 url: "/gliese/read",
                 type: "GET",
                 contentType: "application/json"
             }
         },
         //pageSize: 25,
         schema: {
            data: "data",
            total: "total",
//            total: function(response) {
//                return response.total;
//            },
            model: {
                id: "catalogID",
                fields: {
                    id: {type: "number"},
                    name: {type: "string"},
                    component: {type: "string"}
                }
            }
         },

     },
    pageable: {
        pageSize: 25,
        //pageSizes: true,
        //pageSizes: [10,25,50,100,"all"],
        //input: true,
        numeric: true,
        refresh: true
    },
     columns: [
         {
             field: "id",
             hidden: true
         },
         {
             field: "name",
             title: "Name",
             width: 150
         },
         {
            field: "component",
            title: "Component",
            width: 75
         }
     ],

 };
```

The data displays correctly in the grid, but there are no pages to navigate through, and the message "No items to display" is in the pager bar as well.

Below is an example of the results being returned:

```json
{
    "total": 3803,
    "pageSize": 25,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 12409,
            "name": "Sun",
            "component": "",
            "ra": "00 02 33.8",
            "dec": "+00 16 42",
            "properMotion": null,
            "properMotionDir": null,
            "radialVelocity": null,
            "spectralTypeFull": "G2 V",
            "spectralType": "G",
            "spectralTypeSub": "2",
            "luminosityClass": "V",
            "visualMagnitude": -26.72,
            "absoluteMagnitude": 4.85,
            "parallax": null,
            "bvColor": 0.65,
            "hd": null
        },
        // 24 more results
    ]
}
```

Does anyone see any obvious reasons why the pager bar does not work?

EDIT: Added screenshot per request, updated code to newest attempt.

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: @Shai screenshot added, also updated to my most recent code.

Comment: Passing this response to the Grid shows a total number of records and generates the buttons for page navigation for me https://dojo.telerik.com/axavAKij